# Create executeable for all platforms

Tags: python, windows, macos, executable

I have a python program that reads in a file of names, sorts them alphabetically and then outputs a new sorted text file. I would like to make this into an excuteable so that it works on both Mac and Windows. I tried using pyinstaller

pip install pyinstall
pyinstaller --onefile file_name.py

It output an excuteable that worked on my mac. When I put the executeable on my wife's windows, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For python, an executable only works on the OS for which it was made. If you want to use it on Windows, create it in a computer with Windows, for Mac, create it in a Mac computer.